# Jitsi for corporate usage

Tags: https, udp, jitsi

Is there any possible chance of running the whole Jitsi communication trough the port 443 ?

We tried everything with tunrservers, jvb, nginx settings and nothing work.

Jitsi still want to use port 10000 for videobridge2.

Thanks for any help or links to perfect guide, which can handle app type webrtc without udp ports.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a TURN server (e.g. coturn) that listens on port 443, and users would be able to use that as a relay to videobridge2 if they don't have access to UDP 10000.

You could install coturn on a separate instance and add it to `turncredentials` in your prosody config, or if you could use coturn installed on the same instance and have nginx redirect 443 traffic to it based on hostname.

For a setup guide, see https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/turn#use-turn-server-on-port-443

Comment: @SamuelStanislav I'm afraid I am unable to help you without more details. Also, have you tried asking on https://community.jitsi.org/ ? As far as I can tell, the Jitsi community is a lot more active there than here on SO.